# Sync calendar data to Google Calendar and Outlook in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, google-calendar-api, cakephp-2.4, outlook-calendar

I am creating reservations application in CakePHP and I have action called Calendar, which Uses jQuery datepicker to display calendar. When I click on a date, I get jQuery accordion to display information about reservations on that day.

I want to know if it's possible to use my reservations data and convert it to calendar format used by Google Calendar and Outlook Calendar and sync this data with them.

Answer (score 1):

For Google calendar you can take a look at the API v3 https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ or CalDAV api https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide

Comment: Thank you, I will try at work next week, and if it works for me, I will aprove your answer. Have any thoughts about outlook? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Outlook as the name for me primarily refers to a client. Do you mean Outlook.com or Exchange or something else? There is exchange for developers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn448484.aspx Also try taking a look at ActiveSync http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveSync

Comment: I mean Outlook Calendar :)

Comment: And I really mean that Outlook Calendar is a client which needs to be backed by a server. Which server do you want to talk to?

Comment: I think it is exchange server, as I am not sure about others.